# How to use multiple configurations for multiple containers with only one codebase?

Tags: java, spring, docker, deployment, continuous-integration

I'm trying to host one application which can connect to a few different systems but only to ONE system per runtime/configuration. So if i get a new customer i need to setup the application as well it's configuration file (application.properties). 
Now i want to start using docker to update ALL containers with the new codebase using post commit hooks via Jenkins. Every container should be updated with the new build version of the application. BUT each container should keep it's configuration.

**How to store the configuration files? 
In one centralized folder? How to keep the container linked to the configuration when deploying a newer version of the application?**

The continuous deployment of the application itself already works.

The application itself is build with Spring Boot. 
Spring Boot Cloud Config only covers ONE centralized config for multiple instances isn't it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can refer to this link: [how-to-manage-spring-boot-application-configuration-for-different-environmnets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371247/how-to-manage-spring-boot-application-configuration-for-different-environmnets/50374770#50374770)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the configuration *on the host*, and link it into the container via a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). This way you can pass unique configuration files to your app (via compose, direct `run` commands, etc) and when the container restarts the configuration will persist.